# List variable assigned through Thread Constructor by reference is not working

Tags: java, multithreading, collections

I am initializing class variable of one of my Thread via its constructor through one 
of my service class as below:

```
ProcessMediaThread pThread = new ProcessMediaThread(listMediaPath, mediaType);
pThread.start();
```

where **listMediaPath** is an `ArrayList<String>();` object.
Inside ProcessMediaThread class:

```
public class ProcessMediaThread extends Thread 
{
    private List<String> absoluteMediaPath= new ArrayList<String>();
    private String mediaType;
    public ProcessMediaThread(List<String> absoluteMediaPathList, String mediaType) 
    {
       this.absoluteMediaPath = absoluteMediaPathList;
       this.mediaType= mediaType;
    }
```

My overridden `run()` method:

```
@Override
public void run()
{   
    if(mediaType.equals(MediaType.PHOTO)) //<- mediaType value is retained..
    {       
        for(int i=0;i<absoluteMediaPath.size();i++) // <- here absoluteMediaPath is empty..!!
        {
         //... 
        }
```

One of my friend suggest me to follow different approach **at constructor level**:

```
this.absoluteMediaPath.addAll(absoluteMediaPathList);
```

which worked..!!
Can anyone suggest where exactly the problem is arising and what does `addAll(Collection<? extends E> c);` is doing ?

Comment: It might be possible that you are emptying your `ArrayList` `listMediaPath` after you passed it to the `ProcessMediaThread` constructor.

Comment: @VishalK I rechecked my code, I havn't emptied my arraylist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `addAll`, you're copying the contents of the list into a separate collection within `ProcessMediaThread`. That means changes to it from outside won't affect it. For example, consider:

```
ProcessMediaThread pThread = new ProcessMediaThread(listMediaPath, mediaType);
pThread.start(); 
listMediaPath.clear();
```

With your current code, your new thread may see an empty collection - or it may see a collection which has data and then is suddenly cleared. It's not a good situation to be in. Additionally, `ArrayList` isn't thread-safe, so modifying it in one thread and reading it in another could well cause problems.

When you create a private *copy* (using `addAll`), the `clear()` on the third line above will have no effect, as it's not affecting the same collection that the thread is using.

A few other points:

- I would suggest that you implement `Runnable` separately rather than extending `Thread`. You can then pass an instance of your `Runnable` to a `Thread` constructor; this gives a better separation of "mechanics to run a task on a new thread" and "the task to be run".
- Unless you actually *need* the value of `i` in your loop, you can just use:

  ```
  for (String mediaPath : absoluteMediaPath) {
      ...
  }
  ```
- An alternative to calling `addAll` would be to only initialize your collection in the constructor, using the `ArrayList(Collection)` constructor.

So with all of these together, I'd change your class to something like:

```
public class MediaProcessor implements Runnable {
    private final List<String> absoluteMediaPath;
    private final String mediaType;

    public MediaProcessor(List<String> absoluteMediaPathList, String mediaType) {
       this.absoluteMediaPath = new ArrayList(absoluteMediaPathList);
       this.mediaType = mediaType;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (mediaType.equals(MediaType.PHOTO)) {
            for (String mediaPath : absoluteMediaPath) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}

...

Thread thread = new Thread(new MediaProcessor(listMediaPath, mediaType));
thread.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful reply, one more doubt is, as per your sentence **then is suddenly cleared** where exactly is this happening ? because I am not sharing List variable anywhere other than ProcessMediaThread class.

Comment: @Aman: Well I can't see your code, so I can't tell *what* is sharing the list. But I'm sure something is...